# Reverse integers above 199

Tags: c, integer, reverse

I am solving a problem in C which reverses the integer provided to it.

Code:

```
int reverse(int x) {
    int i, t = 1, y = 0, neg = 0;
    if (x < 0) {
        neg = 1;
        x = -1 * x;
    }
    while (x / t > 1) {
        t = t * 10;
    }
    int p = t;
    while (t >= 1) {
        int d = x / t;
        y = y + p * d / t;
        x = x - d * t;
        t = t / 10;
    }
    if (neg == 1) {
        y = -1 * y;
    }
    return y;
}
```

For some reason the program works incorrectly if `x` is over `199`.

In the first `while` loop, it takes `d` as `0`, and hence an extra `0` is added to the end of the reversed integer.

I know I can just code it to divide by `10` if the input is over `200`, but why it happens and is there any alternate solution possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the statement:

```
while(x/t>1)
```

You are raising `y` more than the power that suits your algorithm.

It should work if you change the condition like this:

```
while(x/t>=10)
```

And here is an alternate solution, which is way simpler than what you're trying to do.

***Steps:***

- 1 - Extract the first digit to the right.
- 2 - Multiply it by 10 and add it to your reversed variable, as if you're pushing it to the left.
- 3 - Divide your number by 10 to remove the digit you just used.
- 4 - Repeat until your number is equal to ***0***.

```
long reverse_modified(long number)
{
    long rem =0 , reversed = 0;

    /*4*/while (number != 0) 
    {
        /*1*/rem = number % 10;
        /*2*/reversed = reversed * 10 + rem;
        /*3*/number /= 10;
    }
    
    return reversed;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code does not work because the test `while (x / t > 1)` is incorrect.  You should write this instead:

```
while (x / t > 9)
```

Note however that your method is complicated. You compute the reversed number starting from the least significant digits instead of from the most significant:

```
int reverse(int x) {
    int y = 0, neg = 0;
    if (x < 0) {
        neg = 1;
        x = -x;
    }
    while (x > 0) {
        y = y * 10 + x % 10;
        x = x / 10;
    }
    if (neg) {
        y = -y;
    }
    return y;
}
```

This function can be further simplified as the integer division always truncates toward zero in C, hence the modulo (`x % 10`) digits that are negative or zero for negative values of `x`.

Here is the simplified version:

```
int reverse(int x) {
    int y = 0;
    while (x != 0) {
        y = y * 10 + x % 10;
        x = x / 10;
    }
    return y;
}
```

Comment: One small correction, in my original solution x/t>=10 would work not 9. But your alternate solutions are actually really good, and I will use the same logic for similar problems ahead. Thanks a lot!!

Comment: @ConfusedCoder:  since `x` is an integer, `x / t >= 10` is the same as `x / t > 9`.

Comment: Shit how could I forget that. I really live up to my username lol